# Position my image next to a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website i have a gray test image and i need to position it next to my image slider. I have tried putting them in the same div but it hasnt worked out as well as i though it would. Could someone show me how to do this within my code. I am new so i am confused with this more than others would be.

Thanks!

My website: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

Press f12 for code. The image slider and the image are near the bottom.

Comment: are you familiar with css float property ?

Comment: Kind of, could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the div css to include (in this case it should be the div with the id "containers" I think)

```
display: inline-block;
```

or since you're using lovely bootstrap you can add classes to both the divs to keep them lovely and gridified! :)

E.g.

```
<div id="container" class="col-xs-6">...</div>
<div id="containers" class="col-xs-6">...</div>
```

Comment: This worked, although my image slider is now static. It used to adjust to the screen. The image that i uploaded does move to the screen though. I just need them to both be next to each other and together be centered on the screen. My site: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: If you move the "imagess" div into the "container" div and set the display for both child elements of "container" to:

display: inline-block;

that should get them side by side and you can edit the "container" element to get it centered etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.inner
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
```